# How to get Axios response header in Typescript

Tags: typescript, axios

I have a rest call which could send back a header I want to store.
Therefore, I need to check if it's there before assigning it.

So far I did something like this:

```
private getHeader(response: AxiosResponse) {
    if (response.headers.has('myheader')) {
      storeHeader(response.headers['myheader']);
    }
 }
```

But Typescript complains about `response.headers.has`. It says:

```
TS18049: 'response.headers.has' is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.
TS2723: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.
TS2349: This expression is not callable.   Not all constituents of type 'string | number | boolean | AxiosHeaders | string[] | ((header: string, matcher?: true | AxiosHeaderMatcher | undefined) => boolean)' are callable.     Type 'string' has no call signatures.
```

Comment: Ugh, Axios... Imagine if the response had a header named `Has`. Then what? Anyways, you should probably use `"myheader" in response.headers` to check instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AxiosResponse#headers is of type `RawAxiosResponseHeaders | AxiosResponseHeaders` and AxiosResponseHeaders is of type `RawAxiosResponseHeaders & AxiosHeaders`.

Method `has` is defined in class `AxiosHeaders`, hence we need to narrow down `response.headers` to `AxiosHeaders` before calling `has` by using `headers instanceof AxiosHeaders`.

```
const headers = response.headers
if (headers instanceof AxiosHeaders && headers.has('myheader')) {
    storeHeader(headers['myheader']);
}
```